# Conversion between `long double` and `std::uintmax_t` loses precision on whole numbers

Tags: c++, casting, floating-point, long-double

I've made a class that allows to split `long double` to an integer value and a binary exponent (for some precise calculations).

My problem is pretty hard to reproduce because the class usually works great but on one specific machine I've tested it on, it was losing a few least significant bits on each conversion. (More on that later.)

Here is the code. (It needs to stay in separate files for this bug to occur.)

`SplitLD.hh`:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

// Splits `long double` into an integer and an exponent.
class SplitLD
{
public: // Everything is public to make the example easier to test.
    std::uintmax_t integer;
    int exponent;

    SplitLD(const long double number);
    operator long double() const;
};
```

`SplitLD.cc`:

```cpp
#include <cfloat>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
#include <climits>
#include "SplitLD.hh"

SplitLD::SplitLD(long double number) // For the sake of simplicity, we ignore negative numbers and various corner cases.
{
    static_assert(FLT_RADIX == 2);
    static_assert(sizeof(std::uintmax_t) * CHAR_BIT >= std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits);
    // The following two operations change the exponent to make the represented value a whole number.
    number = std::frexp(number, &exponent);
    number = std::ldexp(number, std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits);
    exponent -= std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits;
    integer = number; // cast from `long double` to `std::uintmax_t`
}

SplitLD::operator long double() const
{
    long double number = integer; // cast from `std::uintmax_t` to `long double`
    number = std::ldexp(number, exponent);
    return number;
}
```

`main.cc`:

```cpp
#include "SplitLD.hh"

int main()
{
    const long double x = 12345.67890123456789l; // arbitrarily chosen number for the test
    const SplitLD y = x;
    const long double z = y;
    return z == x ? 0 : 1;
}
```

If you try to run this code it will probably work fine.
However, I have one machine, on which the problem can be consistently reproduced.

The conditions that (might) trigger the error are as follow:

- The floating point type has to be `long double`. I tried `float` and `double` and they seem to work fine.
- Both GCC and Clang behave similarly and I can reproduce the problem on both.
- If I put all the code into a single file, it starts to work, possibly because functions are inlined or evaluated during compilation.
- I encountered the error on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) with Ubuntu.
- It may have something to do with hardware configuration.

I've tried to print the binary representation of the numbers (formatted for readability).
(I'm pretty sure that the second group is the sign, the third one is the exponent and the forth one is the mantissa. I'm not sure what the first group is but it's probably just padding.)

Normally the binary values are as follow (for `y` I print only the `integer`):

```
x 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'0'100000000001100'1100000011100110101101110011000111100010100111101011101110000010
y                                                                    1100000011100110101101110011000111100010100111101011101110000010
z 000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000'0'100000000001100'1100000011100110101101110011000111100010100111101011101110000010
```

However, when the error occurs, they look like this:

```
x 000000000000000001111111100110001001110111101001'0'100000000001100'1100000011100110101101110011000111100010100111101011101110000010
y                                                                    1100000011100110101101110011000111100010100111101011110000000000
z 000000000000000001111111100110001001110111101001'0'100000000001100'1100000011100110101101110011000111100010100111101100000000000000
```

What can cause this problem?

Is the program well formed?
Is there an UB somewhere or anything that allows compiler to do some weird optimization?

Here is a [live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/v5dGMrs34). However, its utility is very limited because it works correctly.
(It's includes the code that prints binary representations, which was omitted here to not make the example too long.)

---

Update 1:

I've modified the [test program](https://godbolt.org/z/TYhWPss56) to print binary data after each operation, in order to determine which exact instruction causes the data loss.
It looks like guilty instruction are specifically assignments of `long double` to `std::uintmax_t` and `std::uintmax_t` to `long double`.
Neither `std::frexp` nor `std::ldexp` seems to change the mantissa.

Here's how it looks on the machine where the error occurs:

```
========== `long double` to `std::uintmax_t` ==========
Initial `long double`
000000000000000001111111001100101001101100000010'0'100000000001100'1100000011100110101101110011000111100010100111101011101110000010
Calling `frexp`...
000000000000000001111111001100101001101100000010'0'011111111111110'1100000011100110101101110011000111100010100111101011101110000010
Calling `ldexp`...
000000000000000001111111001100101001101100000010'0'100000000111110'1100000011100110101101110011000111100010100111101011101110000010
Converting to `std::uintmax_t`
                                                                   1100000011100110101101110011000111100010100111101011110000000000
========== `std::uintmax_t` to `long double` ==========
Initial `std::uintmax_t`
                                                                   1100000011100110101101110011000111100010100111101011110000000000
Converting to `long double`
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'0'100000000111110'1100000011100110101101110011000111100010100111101100000000000000
Calling `ldexp`
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'0'100000000001100'1100000011100110101101110011000111100010100111101100000000000000
```

---

Update 2:

It looks like the problem is connected with WSL.
The code works correctly on the same machine when it's ran on a live Linux system or a Linux in a virtual machine.
I cannot install compiler in Windows to test it.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Looks like `std::uintmax_t` to me

Comment: @MooingDuck On machine I was testing, the mantissa seems to have 64 bits (as in 80-bit `long double`) and `std::uintmax_t` also has 64 bits. I even have a `static_assert` that checks if the integer is big enough.

Comment: What are the left sides of `x`, `y`, and `z`? It's sus that the `x` values are different.

Comment: @MooingDuck As far as I can tell, it's padding to make the variable 128 bits instead of 80 for the sake of better alignment. I'm 93% sure of that. In the case of `y`, I just added spaces to align the binary with the mantissa of the floating point.

Comment: @PiotrSiupa: `x` is a long double, which is only 64 bits.  so your outputs don't match your code, so we can't begin to explain them.

Comment: @MooingDuck Are you sure of that? https://godbolt.org/z/PoqG3Y36s

Comment: @PiotrSiupa: That `sizeof (long double) * CHAR_BIT` doesn't mean much of anything.  It tells you how much storage the compiler reserved to maintain alignment.  It doesn't tell you how much of that is part of the value representation and how much is padding.  `long double` on x86 architecture "should" be 80-bits, called "x87 extended precision floating-point"

Comment: @PiotrSiupa: Ok, `long double` is apparently 128 bits, and holds padding, but the point is that your inputs and outputs clearly do not match your code. The IO looks like it's going `SplitLD`->`long double`->`SplitLD`. https://godbolt.org/z/boa59Mq1d gets me close though

Comment: @MooingDuck I did not included the code that prints binaries in the post because it would be too long. You can find the full version by clicking the link to the live demo.

Comment: Unit test `ldexp` and `frexp` on all machines. Also, try `ldexpl` and `frexpl` just in case.

Comment: @n.m. Neither `ldxpr` nor `frexp` seem to be supported by GCC or Clang. However, they don't seem to be guilty. I've printing the binary after each operation now and the data seems to be lost only during the conversion between types. (See edited question.)

Comment: Great, now you can look at the differences in the assembly on different machines, and relate them to differences in gcc versions-configurations.

Comment: @n.m. [The assembly from my machine](https://pastebin.com/v78DJgRR) and [the assembly generated by the compiler explorer](https://pastebin.com/dmKRi1AP) looks very similar. CE removes control instruction from the output and I think this makes most of the differences. I cannot find anything there that would be a significant difference but I'm not that good at assembly. I'm beginning to think that this is just a problem with CPU.

Comment: You can try running under the debugger at the instruction level and examime the registers. If the same machine intruction pfoduces different oiyputs from thr same inputs, it's a ptoblem with the cpu....

Comment: @n.m. I tried and it turns out that I'm not good enough to interpret the contents of the registers. However, I could compare assembly of the running program on both machines (working and not-working) as displayed by gdb. Aside from memory addresses, it looks exactly the same on both so I think it can be safely deduced that indeed one of the machine instructions produces a different result or there would be no bug. I'm going to assume this is the CPU's fault. Most likely, it is not damaged because the computer works but it's just clumsy implementation of some machine instruction by Intel.

Comment: There is an x87 register that controls precision and founding, you mat want to examine it (but I'm out of my depth here).

Answer (score 0):

> What can cause this problem?

Different precisions in `long double` with different machines/compilers.

---

`12345.67890123456789l` risks different unclear bit patterns depending on `long double` precision.  Easier to analyze issues with a *hexadecimal-floating-constant* or maybe with a well understood constant like `4.0L/3` with its repeated pattern:

```
// const long double x = 12345.67890123456789l;

// 4.0L/3
// In binary notation
// Odd number of significant bits
1.010101...010101
// Even number of significant bits
1.010101...0101011
```

---

`integer = number;` is risky. (`integer` is not defined, yet comment implies `uintmax_t`.)

`long double`, on various machines/compilers comes in various flavors: 64-bit, 80-bit with size 80-bit. 80-bit with size 128 bit due to padding, 128-bit and others.

64: `number` ranges from [-0x1F FFFF FFFF FFFF to +0x1F FFFF FFFF FFFF], something like a `int54_t`.

80: `number` ranges from [-0xFFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF to +0xFFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF], something like a `int65_t`.

128: Even wider.

Saving `integer = number` is insufficient to recreate all values with 80/128 and `uintmax_t` is only 64-bit.

Comment: Take one more look at my code. `integer` is `std::uintmax_t` and I also have the assertion `static_assert(sizeof(std::uintmax_t) * CHAR_BIT >= std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits);`. On the machine on which I tested, there seem to be 80-bit `long double` which is 63+1 bits mantissa.

Comment: @PiotrSiupa Even with your assertion, 63+1 bits mantissa, `uintmax_t` as a 64-bit integer remains insufficient to encode all [-0xFFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF to +0xFFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF] distinctively.  That needs 65 bits.

Comment: OK, but let's assume the number is positive, as is stated in the code. We would need to encode only the range [0 to 0xFFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF] in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the system on the WSL solved the problem.
It might be a bug that already has been fixed.